# Access VBA error after splitting database

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have an Access database was created, it's working perfectly. After successfully splitting the database to back and front end I shared the _be file in shared drive and front end file in my local, I tried to run the front end and I am getting error when macro is executing:

[image: Macro error]

I even put the back and front end in my local machine but still I am getting the error, I tried to remove the macros but still getting errors since I am not the one developed this application.

```
Dim fdb As Database
Dim utab As Table, otab As Table
DBEngine.SystemDB = "System.mdw"
Set fdb = CurrentDb() 
Set utab = fdb.OpenTable("Users")
Set otab = fdb.OpenTable("Organization")
```

After tracing the function `findorg()` I found this error

> Item not found in the collection

For this line

```
Set utab = fdb.OpenTable("Users")
```

I tried to change the code to be

```
Set utab = fdb.Rescordsets("Users")
```

But still I am getting the same error.

Note that I am using back and front end, I have all my tables linked.

Comment: What does your macro do?

Comment: macro will call Function findorg() from a modul

Comment: Ok, what does findorg do? Add the code to your question.

Comment: the question was updated

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the VBA code to see which line raises the error?

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you reverse the order of which table you access.  Does the error shift onto `Set otab = fdb.OpenTable("Organization")`?

Comment: yes even that i comment the first line i am getting error in the second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to solve the issue by using **DAO 3.6 object library**, as i found that the current database application is using **DAO 2.5**, so i recompiled the application and fixed all errors. also i managed to rename the functions that's been called by macro, i found that in macro when i write calling function as **findorg()** will not work, but in function name i specify **"findorg"** between double quote, which run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

"Users" table is not linked in the database in which you are running this code. Link it again and check, check for all tables that should also be linked.

Comment: i re linked them but still the same issue

Comment: can you go to the table view and double click the "users" table what do you get?

Comment: i am getting all records available in the table